# firebase javascript token generator

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-app-engine, firebase-authentication

```
    var myDataRef = new Firebase('firebase path');
    myDataRef.authWithCustomToken(firebaseToken, function(error, authData) {
      if (error) {
            console.log("Login Failed!", error);
      } else {
            console.log("Login Succeeded!", authData);
      }
    });
```

My code was like above before Now I changed as below code to migrate from firebase.com to firebase.google.com**

```
    var config = {
        apiKey: "apikey",
        authDomain: "domain",
        databaseURL: "firebase path",
        storageBucket: "storage",
      };

    firebase.initializeApp(config);
    firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(firebaseToken).catch(function(error) {
      // Handle Errors here.
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      // ...
    });
```

with the new code for the same token it is saying invalid token **

Comment: could u describe a little bit more? like what exactly you are trying in terms of code and what sdk versions you are using?

Comment: 'var myDataRef = new Firebase('firebase path');
myDataRef.authWithCustomToken(firebaseToken, function(error, authData) {
  if (error) {
 console.log("Login Failed!", error);
  } else {
 console.log("Login Succeeded!", authData);
  }
});'

**My code was like above before Now I changed as below code to migrate from firebase.com to firebase.google.com**

Comment: 'var config = {
    apiKey: "apikey",
    authDomain: "domain",
    databaseURL: "firebase path",
    storageBucket: "storage",
  };

firebase.initializeApp(config);
firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(firebaseToken).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  // ...
});'

**with the new code for the same token it is saying invalid token **

Comment: where does  `firebaseToken` come from?